# output value of user inputs inside an array java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a program where a user enters how many inputs the user wants. Example if the user enter's 3, then 3 user inputs will appear. The output of this program goes something like this:

```
    ----------------------------------
    Enter How Many Inputs: 3

    enter name:
    rendell //value to be outputted

    enter age:
    20 //value to be outputted

    enter gender:
    male //value to be outputted
    -----------------------------------
```

Now, I want to store those entered values somewhere to be outputted separately after but I have no idea how to do it. I tried to use the ctr1 variable but it only outputs the value of the last user input.

Here is my code:

```
    Object stud1 [][] = {{1,2,3},{"enter name:","enter age:","enter gender:"}};
    String ctr1;

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    for (int i = 0; i<num1;i++){
         System.out.println(pers[1][i]);
         ctr1 = in.readLine();
            }
```

Comment: Is user always going to enter name, age and gender?

Comment: what's pers 2d array content?

Comment: @Nullpointer Depending on how many inputs the user enter. In that output, I entered 3 that's why it prompted me to enter name,age and gender, but if the user enters only 1, then only the name will prompt.

Comment: What if user enters 7?

Comment: @Nullpointer ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only assigning all the input in one reference to the String thus you can print all the input the user just gave.

**solution:**

You can use an array of String to put all the values from the inputted data if the user

**sample:**

```
    String [] choices = { "enter name:","enter age:","enter gender:"};
    String ctr1[];

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    ctr1 = new String[num1];

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        System.out.println(choices[i]);
        ctr1[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ctr1.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            System.out.println("Name: "+ ctr1[i]);
        else if( i == 1)
            System.out.println("Age: "+ ctr1[i]);
        else if( i == 2)
            System.out.println("Gender: "+ ctr1[i]);
    }
```

**result:**

```
Enter How Many Inputs: 3
enter name:
Rod_algonquin
enter age:
12
enter gender:
male
Name: Rod_algonquin
Age: 12
Gender: male
```

Comment: He doesn't need the `BufferedReader` as well as the `Object[]` array